# Qlikview button make selection

Tags: date, button, qlikview

I have a button that when it is clicked I want it to select the last 14 days. This means that if today's date is 2014-03-12, I want it to select all dates between 2013-02-26 and 2014-03-12.

I have a `time_table` with the fields `KEY_timestamp (yyyy-mm-dd)`, `year`, `month`, `day`.

In my button I have an action `Select in Field`, with the field `KEY_timestamp` and I have a `Search String` which looks like

```
=if(
    now() - 14 < KEY_timestamp,
    KEY_timestamp
)
```

Now, to tell you the truth I have no idea how to go about this, and my experience with Qlikview is limited at best... I hope somebody can point me in the right direction. I tried Googling this but I've been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: all dates between 2013-02-16 and 2014-03-12 is not 14 days. Please clarify.

Comment: I meant `2014-02-26`. It's been edited. But that was just an example though so the gist of it is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the search string type only this line:

```
='>' & date(now()-14) &  '<= ' & date(now())
```

If it didn't work properly, add this line in your script:

```
date(KEY_timestamp) as KEY_timestamp_formatted
```

and then replace your select in field with the new column